# Kernel module compilation and KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've noticed that recent kernels (starting from 2.16.24?) don't like if `CFLAGS` is changed in external module Kbuild file. If `CFLAGS` is changed you'll be issued the following error by Linux kernel Kbuild system:

```
scripts/Makefile.build:46: *** CFLAGS was changed in "/some/path". Fix it to use EXTRA_CFLAGS.  Stop.
```

From [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/git-commits-head@vger.kernel.org/msg26519.html):

> External modules have in a few cases modifed gcc option
>       by modifying CFLAGS. This has never been documented and
>       was a bad practice.

Additional `email` from LKML.

Why is it bad idea? What is rational?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, it might be worth mentioning that `EXTRA_CFLAGS` has been deprecated a while ago and is replaced by `ccflags-y`. You can read about the intention of `ccflags-y` in `Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt`, section 3.7.

Basically, this variable allows you to append settings to the set of C compilation flags, within the scope of the file where it is assigned only. You are not supposed to change the global flags, because that *might* have a global impact beyond your own makefile, which is considered bad practice. The check that you mention verifies that indeed, the global flags did not get changed by included makefiles.

It is interesting to check out how `ccflags-y`, formerly known as `EXTRA_CFLAGS`, ends up being used in the build process. Tracing some relevant points (but not all, because that is left as an exercise to the reader ;-) ) shows the following:

`EXTRA_CFLAGS` can still be used, according to `scripts/Makefile.lib`

```
1 # Backward compatibility
2 asflags-y  += $(EXTRA_AFLAGS)
3 ccflags-y  += $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
```

The same file shows how `ccflags-y` ends up in the C compilation flags (and also shows you that you have another variable at your disposal, called `CFLAGS_<filename>.o`):

```
104 orig_c_flags   = $(KBUILD_CPPFLAGS) $(KBUILD_CFLAGS) $(KBUILD_SUBDIR_CCFLAGS) \
105                  $(ccflags-y) $(CFLAGS_$(basetarget).o)
106 _c_flags       = $(filter-out $(CFLAGS_REMOVE_$(basetarget).o), $(orig_c_flags))
...
133 __c_flags       = $(_c_flags)
...
147 c_flags        = -Wp,-MD,$(depfile) $(NOSTDINC_FLAGS) $(LINUXINCLUDE)     \
148                  $(__c_flags) $(modkern_cflags)                           \
149                  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=\#s" $(basename_flags) $(modname_flags)
```

Then in `scripts/Makefile.build`, the compilation rule is defined:

```
234 cmd_cc_o_c = $(CC) $(c_flags) -c -o $@ $<
```

Note that these are all recursively expanded variables, using `=` and not `:=`, which means that your own value of `ccflags-y` gets inserted into the C flags when you define it in your  own makefile.

Finally about `KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC`, which you mention in the title but not in the actual question. This test for changed value of `CFLAGS` can be disabled by giving `KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC` any value -- see `scripts/Makefile.build`

```
47 ifeq ($(KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC),)
48         ifneq ("$(save-cflags)","$(CFLAGS)")
49                 $(error CFLAGS was changed in "$(kbuild-file)". Fix it to use ccflags-y)
50         endif
51 endif
```

The files referenced in this answer were all retrieved today.

Now... not being an expert in this area and looking further into the makefiles after writing this whole story down, there is a thing that I do not understand either. It seems to me that `CFLAGS` is not used in the build system (not implicitly, nor explicitly), but `KBUILD_CFLAGS` is. So I wonder whether this check for changes in `CFLAGS` should actually be a check for changes in `KBUILD_CFLAGS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Linux makefiles build `CFLAGS` in a way which is appropriate for the kernel.
Overriding `CFLAGS` mean you add some flags and may remove some flags. Some of the removed flags may be important for correct compilation.

Comment: If I understand CFLAGS are flags the whole kernel is compiled with and  therefore should not be changed. This means that kernel KBuild system will compile my external module with CFLAGS+EXTRA_CFLAGS. Correct?